# How to get partition to boot and be recognized by Windows after changing disk to dynamic?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, dell-inspiron

My problem is that I shrunk a partition on the  hard disk and there was a unallocated space. Then I made a partition from that unallocated space. After doing this whole disk was converted to dynamic type.

After doing this, I restarted the computer, and Windows 7 didn't boot. After coming BIOS, there is a blinking cursor.

I tried to delete the partition with **Partition logic**, but it shows only one partition having all 150Gb free space. Is there any anthor way to recover the data on other partitions?

I am using a Dell Inspiron 1525.

Comment: Many here recommend testdisk..http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Answer (score 0):

Boot from your Windows 7 CD, and select Repair your Computer instead of Install Now. It should scan and (hopefully) detect your Windows installation. Select Startup Repair and let it run. If it fixes anything, reboot and try again. If it can't detect anything, click Voew Diagnostic Details, then scroll to the last few lines that describe the problem